# XSLT 2.0 - Replace matching pattern in a string

Tags: regex, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the following XML.

```
<GSP>
  <RES>
     <R N="1">
        <MT N="NonEnglishAbstract" V="[DE]Deutsch Abstract text[FR]French Abstract text"/>
     </R>
  </RES>
</GSP>
```

I need the value in `@V` attribute when `@N` is `NonEnglishAbstract`. This value should be after replacing every occurrence of [DE], [FR] or basically any pattern of two capital letters within square brackets, with some HTML content, as in the example output.

I can use a XSLT 2.0 solution.

I suppose I can use some regex pattern along with tokenize() to achieve the result, but don't have the expertise to put it all together.

Example Output:

```
<p class='DE'>Deutsch Abstract text </p>
<p class='FR'>French Abstract text </p>
```

Comment: Can you add a small example of the exact output you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using `xsl:analyze-string`.

Example:

**XML Input**

```
<GSP>
    <RES>
        <R N="1">
            <MT N="NonEnglishAbstract" V="[DE]Deutsch Abstract text[FR]French Abstract text"/>
        </R>
    </RES>
</GSP>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="MT[@N='NonEnglishAbstract']">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="@V" regex="\[([^\[\]]+)\]([^\[]+)">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <p class="{regex-group(1)}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/>
                </p>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<p class="DE">Deutsch Abstract text</p>
<p class="FR">French Abstract text</p>
```

You could change the regex to`\[([A-Z]{{2}})\]([^\[]+)` if you want the match to be more specific.

Comment: Many thanks. I plan to have some CSS applied to the content, with the value inside the brackets as the class names. Something like <p class='DE'>Deutsch Abstract text</p>. Sorry for not being clear in the question.

Comment: @itsbalur - No worries. See my edit for an example that will produce the `p`/`@class` output you need.

Comment: Thanks Again. I am trying out the solution, but unfortunately, the HTML generated doesn't have the <p class="DE">. I suppose I am doing something wrong? It just prints - Deutsch Abstract textFrench Abstract text. Can you think of something obvious?

Comment: ok! I got it working. Something else was causing the problem! Many thanks!